# inserting new values in a list position required both from the keyboard

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying (python) to require from the keyboard a position of a list where later in that position I should add a name and salary also required from the keyboard

I tried the next sentence but it is not working. It is just showing the same values that I already have in the list

Could you help me?

Thanks

```
list1=[('pedro', [333]), ('juan', [9999])]

new=int(input('give me the position'))
name_new=input('give me the name')
salary_new=int(input('give me the salary'))

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if(i==new):
        list1[i].append([name_new,[salary_new]])

print(list1)
```

Comment: `list[i]` should be `list1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to insert something in a list? if so you can use something like :

```
list1=[('pedro', [333]), ('juan', [9999])]

new=int(input('give me the position'))
name_new=input('give me the name')
salary_new=int(input('give me the salary'))

if new > len(list1):
    for i in range(len(list1)-(new-1)+1):
        list1.insert(new, ['', [0]])

list1.insert(new,[name_new,[salary_new]])

print(list1)
```

You probably want a dictionary to do what you expect instead of a list
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

```
dict1= {'pedro':333, 'juan':9999}

new=int(input('give me the position'))
name_new=input('give me the name')
salary_new=int(input('give me the salary'))

if not name_new in dict1:
    dict1[name_new] = salary_new

print(dict1)
```

Comment: Sorry but it is not working. I am trying to add the values in the second position (for example)and the list keeps with the same values

Comment: I updated the code to consider if the user enter a number bigger than the length of the list. Please, consider dict instead of list

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.insert(new, (name_new, salary_new))
```

This will insert the value at the index you need to insert.